# Open a specific url through UILocal notification rather than opening app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to open a specific url through local notification rather than opening the app itself. Is it possible?? if not possible how to detect a particular notification (say my url opening notification) is triggered and instantly directly to that url after the app opens??

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your first question "Is it possible to open a URL from the notification Alert?" is definitely **NO**. But you can find an alternative way to do so that is actually your second question.

There is a Delegate method of UIApplication that gets called whenever your app is launched on clicking on the Local Notification alert. In your AppDelegate.m use this method below to open URL

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Comment: Yes, that what i thought but the now the question is how to detect that local notification (is there any tag or id for this)  since i have also other local notification.

Comment: @russell that is precisely what the (UILocalNotification *)notification argument is for.

Comment: This delegate method has an argument (UILocalNotification *)notification. Use this notification object to detect. For example                                                notification.fireDate

Comment: ok, so i can use notification's property to identify that particular notification as long as it's different than other local notification?

Comment: Exactly. I once used "fireDate" property to identify it.

Comment: Also, if you're firing multiple local notifications, you can always differentiate between them by setting their userInfo dictionary to a recognizable value (e.g. `{"name" : "OpenSettings"}` or `{"name" : "OpenInbox"}`)